# React error while rendering the same component again. Can only mount an unmounted component

Tags: reactjs

```
 <vcDataTable> is a table componnent created in react.

     <div id="app0"></div>
     <div id="app1"></div>
 React.renderComponent(<vcDatatable/>,document.getElementById("app0"));
 React.renderComponent(<vcDatatable/>,document.getElementById("app1"));

 ERROR:
 ------
```

> Invariant Violation:
>   mountComponent(.r[2ly1s].[1].[0].[0].[3].[0].[1][0].[0], ...): 
>        Can only mount an unmounted component.

While rendering a data table component created in react.
 It works fine for all other components like form, tabs etc..

Please help me fix it.. what does this error mean ??

I am rendering the same component into two different div's. it shows me this error.

Comment: You probably keep a reference to one of your components and return it twice (the same instance) from `render()`. It's not a top level component it seems but somewhere deep down in the hierarchy.

Comment: @andreypopp Thanks .. yeah Error was due to the image icon, which i passed in each row.

Answer (score 0):

You probably keep a reference to one of your components and return it twice (the same instance) from render(). It's not a top level component it seems but somewhere deep down in the hierarchy.

– andreypopp